# ghc-mod fails to install

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal, cabal-install

I've just done a fresh install of Arch Linux to a virtual machine and installed GHC (7.6.1), and cabal-install is version 1.16.0-2

I'm trying to get an environment setup for haskell coding, including the ghcmod-vim plugin, which of course requires ghc-mod.

Running cabal install ghc-mod gives several errors

```
Gap.hs:81:19:
    Couldn't match expected type `PprStyle -> String' with `[Char]'
    Expected type: String
      Actual type: PprStyle -> String
    Probable cause: `renderWithStyle' is applied to too few arguments
    In the expression: renderWithStyle d stl
    In an equation for `renderMsg':
        renderMsg d stl = renderWithStyle d stl

Gap.hs:81:35:
    Couldn't match expected type `DynFlags' with actual type `SDoc'
    In the first argument of `renderWithStyle', namely `d'
    In the expression: renderWithStyle d stl
    In an equation for `renderMsg':
        renderMsg d stl = renderWithStyle d stl

Gap.hs:81:37:
    Couldn't match type `SDoc' with `SDoc'
    In the second argument of `renderWithStyle', namely `stl'
    In the expression: renderWithStyle d stl
    In an equation for `renderMsg':
        renderMsg d stl = renderWithStyle d stl

Gap.hs:114:28:
    Couldn't match type `Module' with `ModuleName'
    Expected type: ModSummary -> ModuleName
      Actual type: ModSummary -> Module
    In the second argument of `(.)', namely `ms_mod'
    In the first argument of `map', namely `(IIModule . ms_mod)'
    In the first argument of `(<$>)', namely `map (IIModule . ms_mod)'
```

I don't really understand how these compiler errors are happening given that ghc-mod 1.11.0 seems to have been put on Hackage in June, and my searches for similar issues has turned up nothing.

Thoughts and solutions on how to fix this?

Comment: GHC 7.6.1 was released in September. I'm guessing your options are basically a) downgrade to an older GHC version (7.4.2, maybe?), or b) wait for the maintainer to bring the package up to date.

Comment: You know... I didn't even think about that.  I just looked that the base version was within the right range and thought, "why isn't this working?!"  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to have a look at https://github.com/kazu-yamamoto/ghc-mod. The latest commit is called "GHC 7.6.1 compatibility", so this version might solve your problem.

Comment: Yep!  Checked it out, built it and it works like a charm, thanks!